# Simple Login System in C#

Tags: c#, database, authentication

I was learning C# and was trying to do a simple login System with Database and I came across an error which is System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception.

```
    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = UsernameBox.Text;
        string pass = PasswordBox.Text;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; user id = root; database = mysqlcsharp");
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from mysqlcsharp where username = '"+UsernameBox.Text+"' and password = '"+PasswordBox.Text+"'", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()=="1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("username and password are matched", "info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and Password", "alter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please paste the exception's stack trace?

Comment: Make sure to check the [Connection String documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to make sure you didn't mess up the parameters. You have a really big potential problem here with vulnerability to SQL Injection attacks with the way you're parsing the query, so be careful.

Comment: This is extremely insecure code, wide open to SQL injection attacks. If someone enters `'; drop table users;` as the username or password, the code will go on and execute that as a SQL statement. The connection string uses `root` which means nothing can prevent malicious queries from running. What's missing is the password in the connection string.

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation or interpolation. *DON'T* use `root` to connect to the database. And *never* store the password in the database, either in the clear or encrypted. You need to salt it and hash it with a cryptographically secure hash algorithm at least 1000 times, to ensure the hashed data can't be cracked by simple brute force

Comment: BTW if someone adds `' OR 1=1; --` as the password, the query will return all rows and allow the malicious user to log in

Comment: **Don't** write your own authentication system. Authentication is hard to do securely. Use a library.

Comment: @Manimaran. I would recommend to follow some example. Somthing as shown in this link. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your code for a little bit better and works pretty fine. You can try this for your `Simple Login System`

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = UsernameBox.Text;
        string pass = PasswordBox.Text;
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; user id = root; database = mysqlcsharp"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select * from mysqlcsharp where username = @Username and password = @Password", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.Read() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("username and password are matched", "info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and Password", "alter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    }
```

I use the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("", value);` to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Thank you so much 

Answer (score 1):

This should get you running. But note you should never store the passwords in the database. It would be incredibly easy to hack. You should secure the passwords using a cryptographic hashing algorithm with salted values and hash-stretching (probably a bit much for a simple learning exercise but worth mentioning).

```
    // you should be getting this from configuration, should never be hard-coded
    // also note this connection string is probably wrong and either needs a password or should be made a trusted connection (look it up)
    private readonly string _connectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = mysqlcsharp";

    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = UsernameBox.Text;
        string pass = PasswordBox.Text;
        bool found = false;

        // create your connection with a using block so it will be disposed of properly afterwards
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            // open the connection
            conn.Open();

            // do the same with a command
            using (MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                // do not pass in the variables from the textboxes as plain text as they could contain anything
                // which includes endless ways to hack your application and database.
                command.CommandText = "select count(*) from mysqlcsharp where username = @user and password = @pass";

                // instead add parameters which will block any hacking as the content is not directly included in the query
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", user);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", pass);

                // execute the command - note there is no need to populate a DataTable for such a simple query
                found = (int)command.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
            }

            // close the connection
            conn.Close();
        }

        if (found)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("username and password are matched", "info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and Password", "alter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -2):

You haven’t open connect sql fisrt you need open sql by code try{conn.Open();//your code hể to select data from database }catch(error){};